# Wifi-Ap snap, Simultaneous Client and Access Point now working

Tags: wireless, 20.04, ubuntu-core, hot-spot

I've tried running "Simultaneous STA / AP Mode" using wifi-ap snap as described here:

https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/simultaneous-sta-ap-mode/19964

Tested on Ubuntu Server 20 and Ubuntu Core 20 with no success. Namely the AP reports itself as active but I can't find the network when scanning from another device.

```
$ snap install wifi-ap
$ wifi-ap.config set wifi.channel=6 ## the wifi channel used by wlan0
$ wifi-ap.status ## ap.active: true
$ wifi-ap.config get disabled ## false
```

Tried setting a different ssid/password, channel or hardware_mode. The AP still doesn’t appear.

I can confirm that the wireless chip support STA/AP mode since i could enable this functionality using hostapd and dnsmasq, just hoping that wifi-ap would make this setup easier since I want to use an Ubuntu Core 20 system.

Can anyone provide some advice regarding this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**wifi-ap** seems to be obsolete from what I've been asking on the #snapcraft IRC.

I assume the 'replacement' is [wifi-connect](https://code.launchpad.net/%7Esnappy-hwe-team/snappy-hwe-snaps/+git/wifi-connect).

But you have to build your own snap from source or use **pi-wifi-connect** from the snap store.

I didn't work out how to fully use them yet but I posted the information here just in case.